# Calling function from different threads is blocking?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a class Animal

```
    class Animal
    {
        public:

            int operator()(const int n=4)
            {
                // do something that takes a while(~1 ms)
                return n*5;
            }
    };
```

If I spawn off two threads that each have access to one instance of Animal, will the function calls be run in parallel? Or does the second thread have to wait for the first one to finish?

To be more specific, inside each thread I have a pointer to the same Animal instance and inside the thread I call `(*pointer_to_animal)(10);`

I understand that there my be race conditions when accessing data from both threads, but since all of the variables used inside the function are passed in or created on the stack, there are no race conditions. I'd like the two threads to run in parallel for the same Animal instance.

Comment: C++ doesn't do anything about threading unless you tell it to.  It's up to you to design how the function should handle being called in a multithreaded environment.

Comment: I wonder how programming would ever be possible in an environment with blocking function calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, unless that function does something (e.g., hold a mutex) to prevent parallel execution, it's entirely possible for it to execute in multiple threads simultaneously.

Comment: perfect, this is my desired behavior. Each thread will run the function on its own stack

Comment: @john Beware that multithreading is not something you can guess your way through. It is minefield riddled with subtle gotchas. It may be the hardest thing to get right in application programming, maybe after cyber security. You should get formal education on the requirements of multithreaded programming, such as a dedicated book. The compiler will not help you write thread safe code, and when you do make a mistake, it will probably only manifest a small percentage of the time, making it very difficult for you to track down why your application is randomly crashing or giving impossible results.

Answer (score 2):

> If I spawn off two threads that each have access to one instance of Animal, will the function calls be run in parallel?

Yes.

> Or does the second thread have to wait for the first one to finish?

No, unless you provide your own synchronization, such as with a `std::mutex` or `std::condition_variable`, or equivalent platform primitive.